# Invoking parallel threads of a nslookup command in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

I've written below python script just to invoke parallel threads of a command `nslookup linux-host01 dns-server`, i'm Just trying to flood the DNS Server `dns-server` with multiple number of queries in parallel way.

As an argument to this script i'm passing a `hostlist` file example `linux-host01` , `linux-host02` etc.

To achieve this i'm using `threading` module with the below code and this works fine, However, i'm using the the threading first time hence would like to know if this can be simplified of enhanced further.

```
import os
import threading
from sys import argv, exit


lock = threading.Lock()

hostfile = argv[1]

lst = []
with open(hostfile, 'r') as frb:
    for line in frb:
        lst.append(line.strip("\n"))

threads = []
thread_count = len(lst)

def pop_queue():
    host = None
    lock.acquire()
    if lst:
        host = lst.pop()
        lock.release()
    return host

def dequeue():
    while len(lst) != 0:
        host = pop_queue()
        if not host:
            return None
        else:
            dolookup(host)

def dolookup(name):
    while True:
        os.system("/usr/bin/nslookup %s dns-test01" %name)

for i in range(thread_count):
    t = threading.Thread(target=dequeue)
    t.start()
    print "started thread %s" %i
    threads.append(t)

[t.join() for t in threads]
```

Appreciate any help on this.

Comment: python has [GIL (Global Interpreter Lock)](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock) so threads don't run in parallel.

Comment: Another issue is that `os.system()` is quite an inefficient way to do a hostname lookup; it starts a new shell process, and that shell starts the `nslookup` binary. Try to use [`socket.getaddrinfo()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.getaddrinfo) instead.